# How to fix: Ambari Server - "REASON: Server not yet listening on http port 8080 after 50 seconds. Exiting." inside a container?

Tags: ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

I am new to my docker and Linux. I have Ambari Server installed with a docker on my Linux VM.  It came bundled with the Hortonworks package.  When I start the Ambari Server, I get:

> DB configs consistency check: no errors and warnings were found.
>   ERROR: Exiting with exit code 1. REASON: Server not yet listening on
>   http port 8080 after 50 seconds. Exiting.

I have read that I need to change the timeout setting in the ambari-properties file. Like:

> > ```
> > Edit the "/etc/ambari-server/conf/ambari.properties" and increase the following property value to 120 or 150 seconds.
> >
> > server.startup.web.timeout=120
> > ```
>
> https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/149848/change-the-port-for-ambari-server.html

However, I seems that I have to be inside the container to change the settings, but I can’t start the container. I can not find that folder nor the /var/log/ambari-server.  These folders seem to be in the container. How can I look for the ambari.properties from inside the container?

Comment: Try to see anything in /var/log/ambari-server/ambari-server.log inside your docker container. It will tell you what the actual problem is.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23681830)

Answer (score 0):

- Please have a look at "docker logs" for that container. If possible can you post it over here.
- To change this setting, you need to modify it in Dockerfile of that container and build it again. You may need to add this to your dockerfile

  RUN "sed -i s/server.startup.web.timeout=120/server.startup.web.timeout=150/g /etc/ambari-server/conf/ambari.properties"

If "sed" is not installed inside container, then install it from Dockerfile and remove it after executing that command.

Regards
Neelesh